# Unknown problem - Debian crashes after some minutes

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi

I use Debian (wheezy) on a Raspberry. I use it via ssh and for the first minutes everything works well. Then if I try to use command that are not cd or ls then it seems to crash and I have to wait some minute till I get input/output error.

So I run dmesg to try to find the problem and this is the output.
[image]

So I thought the problem could be the sd card. So I put the backup of the other sd on the new one but the problem is the same.

Does any one have an idea of what could be the problem? I also run fsck but the problem is always here.

Comment: maybe the sd slot is not working right...

Comment: I don't agree, even because it works for the first minutes..It's very strange